# Run out of VRAM using Theano on Amazon cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, neural-network, theano

I'm trying to execute the [logistic_sgd.py](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py) code on an Amazon cluster running the ami-b141a2f5 (Theano - CUDA 7) image.

Instead of the included MNIST database I am using the SD19 database, which requires changing a few dimensional constants, but otherwise no code has been touched. The code runs fine locally, on my CPU, but once I SSH the code and data to the Amazon cluster and run it there, I get this output:
[image]

It looks to me like it is running out of VRAM, but it was my understanding that the code should run on a GPU already, without any tinkering on my part necessary. After following the suggestion from the error message, the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing especially strange here. The error message is almost certainly accurate: there really isn't enough VRAM. Often, a script will run fine on CPU but then fail like this on GPU simply because there is usually much more system memory available than GPU memory, especially since the system memory is virtualized (and can page out to disk if required) while the GPU memory isn't.

For this script, there needs to be enough memory to store the training, validation, and testing data sets, the model parameters, and enough working space to store intermediate results of the computation. There are two options available:

1. Reduce the amount of memory needed for one or more of these three components. Reducing the amount of training data is usually easiest; reducing the size of the model next. Unfortunately both of those two options will often impair the quality of the result that is being looked for. Reducing the amount of memory needed for intermediate results is usually beyond the developers control -- it is managed by Theano, but there is sometimes scope for altering the computation to achieve this goal once a good understanding of Theano's internals is achieved.
2. If the model parameters and working memory can fit in GPU memory then the most common solution is to change the code so that the data is no longer stored in GPU memory (i.e. just store it as numpy arrays, not as Theano shared variables) then pass each batch of data in as `inputs` instead of `givens`. The [LSTM sample code](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/lstm.py) is an example of this approach.